# Hide Product Manufacturer name on Volusion product pages

Tags: css, overriding, product, volusion

I just converted our Volusion website over to the Element upgrade and am now using their site designer to revamp our site. I am more of a designer than coder so forgive my ignorance. :) How can I hide the manufacturer name on all products? Under the Product Name shows the Manufacturer then under that is the price. I want to be able to leave the Manufacturer name in the backend because when we have a price change it's easier for me to sort by vendor.

What code would I use to do this and where would I put it?

I appreciate ANY help anyone can give me, I'm on the struggle bus.

:)
[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmzIj.jpg)

I reached out to Volusion support and was told I could add a custom css file, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Have you asked Volusion how to add a custom CSS file?  It's usually as simple as creating a file called something like custom.css and adding it to the right directory.  The name of the file sometimes matters so their documentation would help you to work that out.  After that if you add a link to your original question we will be able to help you to write the CSS.

Comment: It looks like you could probably use the advanced CSS editor https://help.volusion.com/s/article/StyleEditor

Comment: I tried to ask Volusion, but they only showed me how to edit a block: TAGS, SERVICES & EXTERNAL FILES. But they didn't say which code to use where.
I don't have the Style Editor option any more now that we have upgraded to Site Designer. :(

Comment: I'm not familiar with Volusion I'm afraid.  But you need to work out how to get the CSS working and then we can help you with the styles for it.  But it will be much harder for me to help you understand how to set it up in the first place.  I would go back to Volution to see what more they can do to help.

Comment: okay thanks so much, I'm currently on the support chat with volusion, but last time they weren't able to really help b/c they weren't a developer

Comment: The trouble is nobody here will be able to help either because unless they know Volusion, not enough information is provided.